# Best back end for data intensive Android, iOS app: Drupal or Django or Rails or something else?

Tags: android, backend

We are starting from scratch to develop a couple sophisticated mobile apps. We anticipate supporting iPad, iPhone, Android tablet and Android phones. However, our initial focus will be Android only.

The applications will be used to collect data and send that data to the backend. The whole scope of this project is data collection, data analysis, and data presentation. It's all about data.

What is the right backend technology?

EDIT: Sorry for not providing this info initially. The attraction of Python is the SciPy / NumPy libraries for data presentation and data analysis. I don't think any other platform has libraries that can match these. So Python/Django would seem ideal if there is no problem interfacing with mobile apps...

It will also be nice to use the same technology for the general website and I guess Python/Django is good in that regard too.

Comment: Drupal as backend?? kiddin' me??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python/Django plus SciPy/NumPy proved to be the best option for our project.

> The attraction of Python is the SciPy / NumPy libraries for data
>   presentation and data analysis. I don't think any other platform has
>   libraries that can match these.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any difference between PHP, Python and Ruby in this case. As I understand, backend is going to be used as a database access layer and for nothing more complex. Am I right? If yes, go with technology you know better.

Why do you want to use Drupal for this task? From my point of view, it is better to use something more oriented on high performance and database interaction. Try Yii, Codeigniter or Fat Free PHP frameworks for example.

Django is a good choise as well because it has wonderful administration interface which is being generated by framework automatically. The only thing you should do is to set up models in your app and enable admin module.

Unfortunatelly, I have no RoR experience so I can say nothing about it except that a lot of people say that it is great.

Comment: I updated the question with info about why I believe Python might stand out from the crowd: NumPy and SciPy.

Answer (score 0):

Seriously: Java. You've got ease of use, statefulness and many very very good frameworks. And performance for large datasets is still very very good.
I'd especially recommend the Spring framework and hibernate.

Comment: If we go with Python/Djano, I believe we can leverage SciPy/NumPy for data presentation. If we go with Java, Perfuse (http://prefuse.org/) might be an option, but I think SciPy is superior.